# Get Width and Height of view with match_parent constant

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, dimensions

I have declared `Linear Layout` in my `main_layout.xml`, which has `layout_with` with value of `match_parent` and I am trying to get the width of `Linear Layout` programmatically in pixles, but i am getting width `0`.
Here is my `main_layout.xml`.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.bairnlogixgame.MainActivity" > 

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llTextvieConainter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="@drawable/view_borders"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my `MainActivity` code.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mMainContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llTextvieConainter);

        int mWidth = getBoxDimensions(mMainContainer)[0];
        Log.i(TypeRacingConstants.LOGCAT,
                "Width of box :" + mWidth); 

    }

    private int[] getBoxDimensions(LinearLayout linearLayout) {
        int boxDiamensions[] = { 0, 0 };
        linearLayout.measure(MeasureSpec.EXACTLY, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        boxDiamensions[0] = linearLayout.getMeasuredWidth();
        boxDiamensions[1] = linearLayout.getMeasuredHeight();
        return boxDiamensions;
    }   
}
```

Please help me, where i am getting wrong.

Answer (score 0):

No need to write method getBoxDimensions() to get width. just write below code in onCreate

```
        mMainContainer.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

             int mWidth = mMainContainer.getWidth();
             Log.d("tag", "Width of box :" + mWidth);

        }
    });
```